# Convert French Dates (inconsistent format) to yyyy-MM-dd format

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert the following string (a mixture of French date format and English date format) values into yyyy-MM-dd format.

```
20 Avril 2001
20-Apr-01
22 Mai 2001
22-May-01
29 Mai 2001
8 Juin 2001
15 Juin 2001
18-Jun-01
21 Juin 2001
06-Nov-01
1er décembre 2014
3 Décembre 2014
Le 26 Janvier 2016
8 Février 2016
```

The issue is that the format is not consistent. I am planning to replace the French months as below so all the month values are in English:

```
Janvier     =   January
Février     =   February
Mars        =   March
Avril       =   April
Mai         =   May
Juin        =   June
Juillet     =   July
Aout        =   August
Septembre   =   September
Octobre     =   October
Novembre    =   November
Décembre    =   December
```

Then, check the format (whether it is DD-MM-YY or DD MMM YYYY etc) and convert it to DateTime as below:

```
string iString = "15 June 2001"; //one of the value from the above list.
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT:** I need to import these date values into SQL Server, so I am trying to convert the string values into "yyyy-MM-dd" format.

Comment: Dates have no format. They are just a number and it is only when you try to visualize them that you give them a _format_ Also your code example will never work because the format doesn't match the string

Comment: You not obliged to convert it to english, you can use the CultureInfo "fr-FR" (or "fr-CA", "fr-BE", etc.) depending of your country.
I recommand that you detect all possible format, and loop between all format

Comment: Have you tried `.Parse()` or `.TryParse()`?

Comment: Also _May_ and _Apr_ are not valid French months shortcut. Are they really in your input data set?

Comment: @Steve May and Apr parse perfectly fine in French format

Answer (score 3):

I would have 2 loops: enumerate all values and all formats, add successfully parsed to `List<DateTime>` and unsuccessfully to `List<string>` for further analysis:

```
var results = new List<DateTime>();
var errors = new List<string>();

foreach (string value in values)
{
    bool success = false;

    foreach (string format in formats)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, culture, out var result))
        {
            results.Add(result);
            success = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!success)
    {
        errors.Add(value);
    }
}

return (results, errors);
```

---

There is [an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) accepting `string[] formats` what simplified the implementation even further:

```
public static bool TryParseExact (string s, string[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style, out DateTime result);
```

Like this:

```
var results = new List<DateTime>();
var errors = new List<string>();

foreach (string value in values)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, formats, culture, out var result))
    {
        results.Add(result);
    }
    else
    {
        errors.Add(value);
    }
}

return (results, errors);
```

Answer (score 3):

C# is actually really good at parsing DateTimes in various formats.

```
DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(oTime, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

will get you the correct DateTime for every one of your examples except for `1er décembre 2014` and `Le 26 Janvier 2016`, for which it will throw an exception. TryParse can do these, but will result in bad values. TryParseExact requires you to know the format ahead of time. You do not have to do the month conversion yourself, however. DateTime can handle that.

The best solution would be to validate your inputs. If that is too much work, I would construct a list of all the possible formats you might receive and loop through each with TryParseExact. If you can't know all possible formats, which I'm assuming is the case with examples like `1er décembre 2014`, then you really aren't in a good spot. A dirty but quick solution would be to wrap the code I posted above in a try/catch and then try alternate parsing methods on Exception.